# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException while editing Hashtable/Hashmap

Tags: java, android

I am writing a piece of code that is supposed to combine the values of a hashtable / hashmap if their keys are same . However , when I tried to do this using an iterator it threw `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`. The surprising fact was that this happened only in some cases while in others it functioned perfectly. My code is as follows:

Line to initiate the process. Started from `onPostExecute` of `AsyncTask`:

```
ListFragment.addtolist(getdataformap());
```

Fragment of `ExpandableListView`:

```
 public static class ListFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        public static CustomMap1 datapforputcustom ;
        public static ExpandableListView expandablelistview;
        public static CustomExpandableListAdapter expandableadapter;
        public static Hashtable<Fitems, List<Fnitems>> datapforput = new Hashtable<>();
        public static List<Fitems> mainforput = new ArrayList<>();
        public static View view;
        public static Context getha;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_listfragment, container, false);
            //doddata();
            expandablelistview = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
            expandableadapter = new CustomExpandableListAdapter(((Result) getActivity()).getha(), mainforput, datapforput);
            expandablelistview.setAdapter(expandableadapter);
            getha = ((Result) getActivity()).getha();
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            Permutation.finallist = new ArrayList<>();
            Single_Permutation.singlelist = new ArrayList<>();
   /* doddata();
    expandablelistview = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
    expandableadapter = new CustomExpandableListAdapter(((Result)getActivity()).getha(),mainforput,datapforput);
    expandablelistview.setAdapter(expandableadapter);*/
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static class CustomMap1 extends Hashtable<Fitems, List<Fnitems>> {
            @Override
            public List<Fnitems> put(Fitems value, List<Fnitems> valuelist) {
                List<Fnitems> oldlist = new ArrayList<>();
                Fitems oldkey =value;
                String tester="";

                for (Entry<Fitems, List<Fnitems>> entry : entrySet()) {
                    Log.e("LIST",(entry.getKey().getName()+(value.getName())));
                    if (value.getName().equals(entry.getKey().getName())) {
                        tester = "ojfagsbou";
                        oldkey = entry.getKey();
                        oldlist.addAll(entry.getValue());
                        remove(entry.getKey());
                    }
                }
                // combine your keys as you wish
                List<Fnitems> newvaluelist = new ArrayList<>();
                if (!"".equals(tester)) {
                    System.out.println(oldkey.getName()+"oldkey");
                    newvaluelist.addAll(oldlist);
                    newvaluelist.addAll(valuelist);
                } else {
                    newvaluelist.addAll(valuelist);
                    System.out.println(oldkey.getName()+"oldkey");
                    mainforput.add(oldkey);
                }
                return super.put(oldkey, newvaluelist);
            }
        }
        public static void doddata() {
           /* Fitems fitems1 = new Fitems();
            Fitems fitems2 = new Fitems();
            Fnitems fnitems1 = new Fnitems();
            Fnitems fnitems2 = new Fnitems();
            Fnitems fnitems3 = new Fnitems();
            Fnitems fnitems4 = new Fnitems();
            fitems1.setName("AAA");
            fitems2.setName("BBB");
            fnitems1.setName("AAAa");
            fnitems2.setName("AAAb");
            fnitems3.setName("BBBa");
            fnitems4.setName("BBBb");
            List<Fnitems> listfnitem1 = new ArrayList<>();
            List<Fnitems> listfnitem2 = new ArrayList<>();
            listfnitem1.add(fnitems1);
            listfnitem1.add(fnitems2);
            listfnitem2.add(fnitems3);
            listfnitem2.add(fnitems4);*/
            mainforput=new ArrayList<>();
            datapforputcustom = new CustomMap1();
            datapforput = new Hashtable<>();
            ArrayList<String> strind = new ArrayList<>();
            for(Map.Entry<String,Map<String,Integer>> entry1 : Result.cart_names1.entrySet()){
                strind.add(entry1.getKey());
            }
            Log.e("ERROR", "thisis the list for god's sake " + Result.couldthis+datapforput.toString());
            if (Result.couldthis.size() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < (Result.couldthis).size(); i++) {
                    Fitems fitems3 = new Fitems();
                        fitems3.setName(Result.couldthis.get(i));
                        Fnitems fnitems5 = new Fnitems();
                        fnitems5.setName(strind.get(i));
                        List<Fnitems> listfnitem3 = new ArrayList<>();
                        listfnitem3.add(fnitems5);
                    Log.e("RE",fitems3.getName()+" "+listfnitem3.get(0).getName());
                        datapforput.put(fitems3,listfnitem3);
                    }
                }
            datapforputcustom.putAll(datapforput);
            Log.e("UGF",datapforputcustom+" cusom");
            //datapforput.put(fitems1, listfnitem1);
           // datapforput.put(fitems2, listfnitem2);
           // mainforput.add(fitems1);
           // mainforput.add(fitems2);
        }

        public static ListFragment newInstance() {
            ListFragment fragment = new ListFragment();
            Log.e("ERROR", "man .... " + fragment.getTag());
            return fragment;
        }

        public static void addtolist(ArrayList<String> dataforputting) {
           Log.e("ERROR", "thisis the list 3" + (dataforputting));
            //if (expandableadapter != null){
            expandableadapter.clear();//}
            Log.e("INFO", "This is mainforput" + mainforput + "This is dataforput" + datapforput);
            doddata();
            Log.e("INFO", "This is mainforput" + mainforput.get(0).getName() + "This is dataforput" + datapforputcustom);
            expandableadapter = new CustomExpandableListAdapter(getha, mainforput, datapforputcustom);
            expandablelistview.setAdapter(expandableadapter);
        }


    }
```

Stack:

```
07-16 22:32:22.042 16896-16896/nf.co.riaah.chutte E/INFO: This is mainforput[]This is dataforput{}
07-16 22:32:22.042 16896-16896/nf.co.riaah.chutte E/ERROR: thisis the list for god's sake [First, Second, Second, First, Second]{}
07-16 22:32:22.042 16896-16896/nf.co.riaah.chutte E/RE: First Onion
07-16 22:32:22.042 16896-16896/nf.co.riaah.chutte E/RE: Second Broccoli
07-16 22:32:22.042 16896-16896/nf.co.riaah.chutte E/RE: Second Curd
07-16 22:32:22.042 16896-16896/nf.co.riaah.chutte E/RE: First Milk
07-16 22:32:22.042 16896-16896/nf.co.riaah.chutte E/RE: Second Carrot
07-16 22:32:22.042 16896-16896/nf.co.riaah.chutte I/System.out: Secondoldkey
07-16 22:32:22.042 16896-16896/nf.co.riaah.chutte E/LIST: SecondSecond
07-16 22:32:22.042 16896-16896/nf.co.riaah.chutte I/System.out: Secondoldkey
07-16 22:32:22.043 16896-16896/nf.co.riaah.chutte E/LIST: SecondFirst
07-16 22:32:22.043 16896-16896/nf.co.riaah.chutte I/System.out: Firstoldkey
07-16 22:32:22.043 16896-16896/nf.co.riaah.chutte E/LIST: SecondSecond
07-16 22:32:22.043 16896-16896/nf.co.riaah.chutte D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
07-16 22:32:22.044 16896-16896/nf.co.riaah.chutte E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: nf.co.riaah.chutte, PID: 16896
                                                                    java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
                                                                        at java.util.Hashtable$HashIterator.nextEntry(Hashtable.java:727)
                                                                        at java.util.Hashtable$EntryIterator.next(Hashtable.java:778)
                                                                        at java.util.Hashtable$EntryIterator.next(Hashtable.java:776)
                                                                        at nf.co.riaah.chutte.Result$ListFragment$CustomMap1.put(Result.java:184)
                                                                        at nf.co.riaah.chutte.Result$ListFragment$CustomMap1.put(Result.java:177)
                                                                        at java.util.Hashtable.putAll(Hashtable.java:425)
                                                                        at nf.co.riaah.chutte.Result$ListFragment.doddata(Result.java:246)
                                                                        at nf.co.riaah.chutte.Result$ListFragment.addtolist(Result.java:265)
                                                                        at nf.co.riaah.chutte.Result$SetMap.onPostExecute(Result.java:1078)
                                                                        at nf.co.riaah.chutte.Result$SetMap.onPostExecute(Result.java:996)
                                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
                                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
                                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:139)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5298)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
07-16 22:32:22.044 16896-16896/nf.co.riaah.chutte D/AppTracker: App Event: crash
07-16 22:32:22.080 16896-16896/nf.co.riaah.chutte I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 16896 SIG: 9
07-16 22:32:23.252 19872-19872/nf.co.riaah.chutte E/ThreadedRenderer: set Thread 19901 affinity cpu 3failed
```

A Million Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please read: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Hashtable.html

The opening description of the `Hashtable` covers the `ConcurrentModificationException` you are experiencing; the documentation states that `Hashtable`'s iterators are fail-fast and will throw the `ConcurrentModificationException` whenever the underlying `Hashtable` changes under the iterator and the iterator wasn't used to make those changes.

In the stack, `putAll()` is listed -- so it is modifying the underlying structure and causing the Iterators to fail. Is there anyway you can orchestrate the two events to not occur simultaneously? If you can figure out a way to do that, then I think you'll have the issue resolved.

Comment: I was able to solve it by not actually editing the hashtable through which I was iterating , but by adding the updated items in a new hastable

Answer (score 0):

> ConcurrentModificationException happen because you did not lock access to REMOVE method of your HashTable, therefore somebody can insert and remove item while you iterate the HashTable in your Overridden PUT method.
>
> Please check my class, this one can Certainly reproduce your error at all times. And the fix is found in "CustomMapImproved" class.

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class TestHashTable {

public static class CustomMap1 extends Hashtable<String, List<String>> {
    @Override
    public List<String> put(String value, List<String> valuelist) {
        List<String> oldlist = new ArrayList<>();
        String oldkey = value;
        String tester="";

        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue().get(0)!=null 
                    && value.equals(entry.getValue().get(0))) {
                tester = "arbitrary";
                oldkey = entry.getKey();
                oldlist.addAll(entry.getValue());
                remove(entry.getKey());
            }
        }
        
        // combine your keys as you wish
        List<String> newvaluelist = new ArrayList<>();
        if (!"".equals(tester)) {
            //System.out.println(oldkey.getName()+"oldkey");
            newvaluelist.addAll(oldlist);
            newvaluelist.addAll(valuelist);
        } else {
            newvaluelist.addAll(valuelist);
        }
        return super.put(oldkey, newvaluelist);
    }
}

public static class CustomMapImproved extends Hashtable<String, List<String>> {
    private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    
    @Override
    public List<String> put(String value, List<String> valuelist) {
        lock.lock();
        try{
            List<String> oldlist = new ArrayList<>();
            String oldkey = value;
            String tester="";

            Iterator<Map.Entry<String, List<String>>> iterator = entrySet().iterator();
            java.util.Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry;

            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                entry = iterator.next();
                if (entry.getValue().get(0) != null && value.equals(entry.getValue().get(0))) {
                    tester = "arbitrary";
                    oldkey = entry.getKey();
                    oldlist.addAll(entry.getValue());
                    iterator.remove();//use this instead of remove(Object);
                }
            }
            
            // combine your keys as you wish
            List<String> newvaluelist = new ArrayList<>();
            if (!"".equals(tester)) {
                //System.out.println(oldkey.getName()+"oldkey");
                newvaluelist.addAll(oldlist);
                newvaluelist.addAll(valuelist);
            } else {
                newvaluelist.addAll(valuelist);
            }
            return super.put(oldkey, newvaluelist);
        }finally{
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public List<String> get(Object obj){
        lock.lock();
        try{
            return super.get(obj);
        }finally{
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public List<String> remove(Object obj){
        lock.lock();
        try{
            return super.remove(obj);
        }finally{
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[]args){
    //final Hashtable<String,List<String>> map = new CustomMap1();
    final Hashtable<String,List<String>> map = new CustomMapImproved();
    final List<Thread> tList = new ArrayList<Thread>();
    final int reps = 1000;
    int thread = 100;
    
    for(int i=0;i<thread; i++){
        final int idx = i;
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                for(int i=0;i<reps;i++){
                    if(idx%2==0){
                        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                        list.add("value"+idx);
                        map.put("value"+idx,list);
                    }
                    else{
                        map.remove("value"+idx);
                    }
                }
                
            }
        });
        t.start();
        tList.add(t);
    }
    
    for(Thread t : tList){
        try {t.join();} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I was able to solve it by not actually editing the hashtable through which I was iterating , but by adding the updated items in a new hastable

Comment: Glad to hear that.. btw have you tried concurrenthasmap? It is fully compatible with hash table, and does not need to copy updated item to new hashtable. Link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html